# Dhtmlx gantt can't be shown inside an ion-content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dhtmlx

I am developing a ionic-angular application in which I need some gantt charts, I tried to use the Dhtmlx library but when I insert the gantt chart inside an ion-content the gantt disappear (but with inspect I can see the empty space where would be the gantt).

Anyone has an idea on how I can resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: probably is a sort of race condition beacuse the gantt is inizialized inside the ngAfterViewInit() (not in the ngInit as in the [example](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/dhtmlx-gantt-chart-usage-angularjs-2-framework/)), there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: The code is simply an html with `<ion-content>
  <gantt></gantt>
</ion-content>` where the gantt is exactly the code in this tutorial https://dhtmlx.com/blog/dhtmlx-gantt-chart-usage-angularjs-2-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when Gantt is initialized, the container has 0 pixels for the width and height, so, Gantt is shrunk.
As a workaround, you can initialize Gantt after a timeout.

Here is the demo:

https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/9d735c16565563829fab087d96937cf7/ionicframework+gantt.zip